# Dismissing keyboard slides the view either up or down

Tags: android, webview

Using android webview, whenever I dismiss the keyboard it either slides the view up or down. Going through similar issues on SO, I tried using following 2 individually:

- `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` - This does prevent sliding of the webview, but now whenever keyboard is up, some of my UI elements are under the keyboard which prevents user from typing/interacting with those elements hidden under the keyboard. I tried adding a scroll to the webview, but scroll doesn't show up with this option. It works fine, if I don't add this property.
- `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` - The issue still remains if I use this property.

Layout width and height on my webview is fill_parent.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Could anything else help me here?

Comment: THat's how an onscreen keyboard works.  Either you need to put the keyboard on top of UI elements, or you need to slide the view up.  One or the other has to happen-  its not like there's a separate place it can go.

Comment: I was wondering if I can make scroll work with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan". That way I can atleast scroll down to the UI element. Presently with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" scroll doesn't work. If I don't add this property, scroll functions normally.